# Calculate the diameter of an inscribed circle inside a sector of circle

Tags: circles

$AOB$ is a sector of a circle with center $O$, angle = 45° and radius $OA=10$.
Find the radius of the chord inscribed circle in this sector such that it touches radius $OA$, radius $OB$ and arc $AB$.

[image]

Comment: Anything between $0$ and $5$.

Comment: I need a formula, not a forcast

Comment: $$0<r<5$$ if you prefer.

Comment: @NguyenVietAnh With the info given, "Between $0$ and $5$" is all we can say. We need something else, like the length of either the line segment $AB$ or the circle arc $AB$, or the angle at $O$. In other words, we need to know how big the sector is.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that we have length of OA, angle at O

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The geometry in

[image]

says
$$
r=(R-r)\sin\left(\frac\theta2\right)
$$
Therefore, we can solve for $r$:
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{r=R\,\frac{\sin\left(\frac\theta2\right)}{1+\sin\left(\frac\theta2\right)}}
$$
To find $\theta$ from $R$ and $r$, we can use
$$
\sin\left(\frac\theta2\right)=\frac{r}{R-r}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $\theta$ is the sector angle, a coordinate geometry solution would be to consider a circle  $x^2 + y^2 + 2gx + 2fy + c =0 $ inside the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 100$. Now our required circle touches lines $y=0$, $y=\tan \theta x $ and the circle. I suppose you can do it now. For tangency to lines, distance of centre from line is equal to radius, add for touching circle, distance between centres = difference of radii.

Comment: Poorly, I could not fully understand what you meant. If you do not mind, please write down a complete formula base on 2 input, length of OA and sector angle (for e.g. 10 and 45°)

Comment: As I do not have any data, I am not sure, but try this: Radius of inscribed circle = $$ \frac{R}{1+ \sqrt{(1+ \frac {\sec^2 \theta + 2 \sec \theta + 1}{\tan^2 \theta})}}$$

Comment: centre of a circle, inscribed in an angle, is on the bisector of this angle, but how we prove that touchpoint of this circle with an arc lies on this bisector.